# Using LIMIT in Neo4j cypher subquery does not limit the amount of rows returned

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a subquery where I need to get just the first row. Using LIMIT 1 in the subquery I thought I would get just just the first but I am still getting all the rows. This is my cypher snippet:

```
 WITH t,s
 CALL {
              WITH t,s
              MATCH (t)-[:PROVIDES]->(s)
              WITH t
              LIMIT 1
              RETURN t AS tech
            }
      
 RETURN   tech
```

I am using Neo4j Desktop 4.5. I have also tried

```
RETURN t AS tech LIMIT 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?
**EDIT**
my reason for requiring the first tech only is that I actually need to assign that that tech to a job like so:

```
CREATE (tech)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]->(s)
```

The subquery is actually querying a list of multiple techs and just want to choose the first one based on the query.

Answer (score 1):

The first line "WITH t,s" is causing multiple rows and not inside the subquery "CALL".  Your subquery CALL is correct to return one node t as tech but the entire query is doing a cartesian product with tech and t,s.  Thus you are getting multiple values of tech.  Below are suggested fixes.

Option#1:
Simply return one tech value using LIMIT 1.

```
WITH t,s
 CALL {
              WITH t,s
              MATCH (t)-[:PROVIDES]->(s)
              RETURN t AS tech 
            }
      
 RETURN tech LIMIT 1
```

Option#2:
Collect all values of tech [collect (tech)] then get the first item (index: 0) on that list.  This will surely return one row of tech.

```
 WITH t,s
 CALL {
              WITH t,s
              MATCH (t)-[:PROVIDES]->(s)
              RETURN t AS tech
            }
      
 RETURN  collect(tech)[0] as tech
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make it a little clearer as to why I need just the first tech.

Comment: based on your answer I am now thinking that the subquery is not going to do what I want....given that it will always 'merge' its result into the imported WITH values.....which in my case consists of multiple techs and 1 service......if you agree can you suggest an alternative query?

Comment: I think I got it.....using:  WITH collect(t)[0] as tech, s  ....I can then do the assignment: CREATE (tech)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]->(s) without the subquery